# Static images disappeared after using AWS for Heroku site

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku, web-hosting

I made a site for Heroku using Django and I got it to the point where it kept all the static images and files on Heroku just fine but the images the user uploads got deleted on dyno reset; that's why I wanted to use AWS to host the files the user uploads.

This is the code I am using in my settings:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('my key')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('my secret key')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my bucket name'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

STATIC_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

I added the "eu-west-1" part in the static URL because it was in the bucket's URL but not in my site's src for the image.

The problem is that now most of my JavaScript and CSS have disappeared as have all my static files that were previously just on Heroku and worked fine, furthermore the files that the user uploads also don't show up and the src doesn't containt the "eu-west-1" that I added (and it doesn't work without that part either).

Can somebody help me make it so that my static files are on Heroku as before while user uploaded files are on AWS?

Comment: You can check the URL of your object from AWS S3 console (it looks correct to me), the other thing you need to do is to make it public so it can be fetched by the app

Comment: I checked the URL on the AWS site and it is not the same as the one the app tries to get. As I said, that is why I added "eu-west-1" myself but for some reason it doesn't make a difference. The bucket isn't completely public but the tutorial I followed had me set the permissions so an app could fetch it.